# Comparison states and evolution calculation based on user selecting year Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a powerbi report that compares between compaigns of a brand. the user dynamically selects two years: Year1 and Year2 from the slicer pane and two compaigns. the report shows two sets of carts, the first has these information: Total Stores, Profit, ROI (return on investment) for Year1 and the evolution of those comparing them to year2. the second set of carts presents the same data but adds a filter layer : "comparable". comparable means that we will only filter on same stores and dates of the year in those compaigns. so for example if we have a sephora store in London Street that was part of the compaign in year1 and not year2, it will show in the first set of carts and will not show in the second.
the complexity is the fact that Powerbi do not support parameters in measures
i tried to create a disconnected table having the distinct years existing in my year column in my main table. I then created two slicers : Year1, Year2. i created two cart visuals : totalstores_year1, Total stores_year2. i edited interactions so slicer year1 filters visual totalstores_year1 and same for year2. the problem is that totalstores_evolution that calculates the store evolution between year1 and Year2 is blank because it cannot be linked to any filter, it should include the two and that is not possible.chatgpt turns in circles and can't provide an answer. it proposed bookmarks but i have the same filtering problem
here is the Dax measures

here is the Dax measures

```
TotalPDV_Year1 = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(CR[code PDV]),
    FILTER(CR, CR[Année] = SELECTEDVALUE(_Mesures[Année]))
)
TotalPDV_Year2 = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(CR[code PDV]),
    FILTER(CR, CR[Année] = SELECTEDVALUE(_Mesures[Année]))
)
TotalStores_Evolution = 
VAR TotalStores_Year1 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(CR[code PDV]), CR[Année] = SELECTEDVALUE(_Mesures[Année]))
VAR TotalStores_Year2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(CR[Code PDV]), CR[Année] = SELECTEDVALUE(_Mesures[Année]))
RETURN
DIVIDE(
    TotalStores_Year1 - TotalStores_Year2,
    TotalStores_Year2
) * 100
```